# How to see my app users are from where?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, location

development of my app has finished, but I want to have general information about my app users.

- How can I know they are from which Store/country?  store/country-specific downloads
- How can I know which languages they are using for focusing on it more.
- Will such these informations appear on the dev center or I should have my own server for receiving these information?
- Which codes I need, where can I start?

I know I can use device location, but I don't want to use this option

(sorry I couldn't find anything useful by searching)

**Update** I don't want these informations locally (providing it to the user himself) But I want to know who are my users after sending it to the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I know they are from which Store/country? store/country-specific downloads

That information is already available in the Store statistics

> How can I know which languages they are using for focusing on it more.

Read the [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) and [Thread.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx) , if you want to know what local language/culture the user is user.

The store is bound to the country specified for the users live account.